# Update specific state in Redux with reducer

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I would like to know, how can I update a specific value in state. I have my state config, and I would like to update the 'offset' value without modify the limit or total value, just set a new offset with this.props.setParams()...

With this function, I would like to modify offset this.props.setParams({ offset: 10}), or limit this.props.setParams({ limit: 40}), etc... just send a params and modify directly the associate state.

**searchList.js**

```
this.props.setParams({ offset: 10})
```

**actions-search.js**

```
export function setFilters(newFilters) {
    return {
        type   : SEARCH.SET_NEW_FILTERS,
        payload: newFilters
    };
}

export function setParams(newParams) {
    return {
        type   : SEARCH.SET_NEW_PARAMS,
        payload: newParams
    };
}
```

**reducer-search.js**

```
...

    /*State : CONFIG*/
    /*config: {
        filters : {
            ...
        }
        params: {
            offset: 0,
            limit: 25,
            total: 100
        }
    }*/

case SEARCH.SET_NEW_FILTERS :
    let newFilters = action.payload;

    return {
        ...state,
        config: {
            ...state.config,
            filters : {
                ...state.config.filters,
                newFilters
            }
            params : {
                ...state.config.params
            }
        }
    };
case SEARCH.SET_NEW_PARAMS :
    let newParams = action.payload; // {offset: 10}

    return {
        ...state,
        config: {
            ...state.config,
            filters : {
                ...state.config.filters
            }
            params : {
                ...state.config.params,
                newParams
            }
        }
    };
....
```

Curently, I must write this :

```
return {
    ...state,
    config: {
        ...state.config,
        params : {
            ...state.config.params,
            offset : newParams.offset
        }
    }
};
```

How can I have more "generic" in my reducer ? No specify a specific property,but more global.

Just send an object "params" in my action creator, example : this.props.setParams({offset: 30, total: 120}) ?

Comment: What's the problem? Is the action not dispatched? Or is the state not updated correctly? Please be specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actual behavior**

Your code is adding `newFilters` and `newParams` as properties. That way you would have to access `offset` as:

```js
state.config.params.newParams.offset
```

**Solution**

To access those new filters or params directly with

```
state.config.params.offset
```

You should spread `newFilters` and `newParams`, using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...`, in your reducers:

```js
            filters : {
                ...state.config.filters,
                ...newFilters
            }
```

and

```
            params : {
                ...state.config.params,
                ...newParams
            }
```

The spread syntax will add (or replace) the inner properties of your payload, `newFilters` and `newParams`, to the properties of `state.config.filters` and `state.config.params` respectively.

**Improvements**

To simplify your reducer you could spread `action.payload` directly and remove some probably unnecessary spreads:

*actions-search.js*

```
...

case SEARCH.SET_NEW_FILTERS :
    return {
        ...state,
        config: {
            ...state.config,
            filters : {
                ...state.config.filters,
                ...action.payload
            }
        }
    };
case SEARCH.SET_NEW_PARAMS :
    return {
        ...state,
        config: {
            ...state.config,
            params : {
                ...state.config.params,
                ...action.payload
            }
        }
    };
...
```

Comment: Thank you ! Logic... :-) Do you know if use two CASE in my reducer to manage filters and params is useless or it's a best practice ? I ask me if I write two CASE or just one CASE...

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your app. If you just need two actions on your reducer, your code works perfectly IMO.